# SQL Query to find attributes that don't match for secondary matching attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Need to create a query that finds a set of records like the following:

```
ID  |  Address    |  Unit | Status

1   |555 Smith Rd | Apt A | Success
2   |555 Smith Rd | Apt B | Success
3   |555 Smith Rd | Apt C | Success
4   |555 Smith Rd | Apt D | Failure
```

I need to select records where Address field matches and where the status field is NOT matching. Ideally I would like to display the group of records like the example above.

Comment: Relevant username.  If you have tried, what?

Comment: what does your query look like now? give us something to work off of.

Comment: My username says it all, I really am not sure where to begin on this, I have never run into this type of problem before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions for this:

```
select id, address, unit, status
from (select t.*, min(status) over (partition by address) as mins,
             max(status) over (partition by address) as maxs
      from table t
     ) t
where mins <> maxs
order by address;
```